# Deployed Jenkins on an EKS cluster with EFS for persistence... but I still loose all configs if pod restarts

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

Hey so I deployed Jenkins on an EKS cluster the deployment is simple

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        ports:
          - name: http-port
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: jnlp-port
            containerPort: 50000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-vol
            mountPath: /var

      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-vol
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: jenkins-claim
```

the pv/pvc show up fine

```
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
jenkins   5Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    jenkins/jenkins-claim   efs-sc                  61m
```

but when every the jenkins pod restarts (to simulate an update) I loose all jenkins configs

Comment: try once with mount path : `/var/jenkins_home`

Comment: tried that first... there was another post that suggested /var... but this doesnt work either

Comment: Suggest stepping through this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/deploying-jenkins-on-amazon-eks-with-amazon-efs/  and see if you are missing a step

Comment: followed everything but doesnt work